Number Cards with wavey edges, and shadows behind them
This is my mwe, which is not very good. I want to create something like in the picture attached, and simple, and also so I can make larger and smaller, and individual cards so I can change the numbers on the cards the shadows in the backgroud would be nice, too.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            \node[draw=none,shade, scale=3,
            top color=blue!40,
            bottom color=blue!5,
            rounded corners=6pt,
            blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}
            ] {\sffamily\bfseries\large 1 };
                        \node[tape,draw=none,shade, scale=3,
            top color=blue!40,
            bottom color=blue!5,
            rounded corners=1pt,
            blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow blur extra rounding=1.3pt}
            ] at (5,0){\sffamily\bfseries\large 2};
\node [below] at (-2,0.5) { \huge Jack};    
                \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}


If I recall correctly, you can achieve this by the decoration library. Howver, it slows down or even aborts compilation, to my experience ...

Thanks, I will just accept any square cards with numbers on them

There are two packages which might be interesting for you: https://ctan.org/pkg/playcards , https://ctan.org/pkg/jeuxcartes ?

You could use the star shape with rounded corners and set the star point ratio to get your rounded cards.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, shadows}
\tikzset{
    card/.style={
        star, star points=4, star point ratio=1.47, 
        draw, rounded corners, shape border rotate=45, fill=white,
        general shadow={fill=gray!20, shadow scale=1.2}, 
        inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7mm, font=\sffamily\bfseries, 
        yscale=1.4, scale=2
    }
}

\newcommand{\card}[2][]{\tikz[baseline, #1]{\node[card]{#2};}}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{12}
Jack \foreach \c[count=\n] in {7,3,2,6,9,7} {\card[transform shape, rotate=6-2*\n+3*rand]{\c}\;\;}

\bigskip
Jodie \foreach \c[count=\n] in {4,8,9,0,0,7} {\card[transform shape, rotate=6-2*\n+3*rand]{\c}\;\;}

\bigskip
Scaled \foreach \c[count=\n] in {A,B,C,D,E,F} {\card[transform shape, scale=.7]{\c}\;\;}

\bigskip
Single \card{?}
\end{document}


This is best I could come up with borrowed something from the website, which I don't understand and played with, can someone explain an make simpler. It does work
    % !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{anttor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

%\renewcommand\ULthickness{4pt}
%\setlength \ULdepth{16pt}
\begin{document}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cardwidth}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cardheight}{3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\stripwidth}{0.6}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\strippadding}{0.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\textpadding}{-0.3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ruleheight}{0.1}
    
    \newcommand\myfontsize{\fontsize{50pt}{50pt}\selectfont}

Jack and Jodie were playing a card game. Each player received 6 cards.
The aim of the game was to create the largest number by rearranging their hand of cards.
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [] (0,0) ;
    \node[align=left] at (0,2) { \Large \color{blue}  \textbf{Jack's } \\ \large \color{blue} \textbf{Cards }  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right,   ] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize 7    } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize 3    } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize 2    } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize 6    } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize 9    } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize 7    } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}   

\vspace{0.2cm}



\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [] (0,0) ;
    \node[align=left] at (0,2) { \Large \color{red}  \textbf{Jodie's } \\ \large \color{red} \textbf{Cards }  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=red] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right,   ] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize  4   } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=red] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize 8   } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=red] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize  9  } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=red] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize 0   } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=red] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize 0    } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=0.2cm, very thick,color=red] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth,\cardheight);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1cm] (\strippadding,\strippadding) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding);
    \node[text width=(\cardwidth-\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm,below right] at (\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,\cardheight-\textpadding) {
        {          }\\
        
        \vspace{0.9cm}
        
        { \myfontsize 7    } 
        \vfill   };
\end{tikzpicture}   


\end{document}

